# FastAPI swagger don't use custom header

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, fastapi

I want to add "Authorization" header to the my FastAPI application.
I did it by [documentation](https://github.com/IndominusByte/fastapi-jwt-auth/blob/master/examples/generate_doc.py), but when i try to execute request in the swagger - it doesn't work(swagger don't use custom header), i have "Missing Authorization Header" error
[Error in the swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoJRO.png)

Comment: It seems like you've only added the header information _to the documentation_ - so it won't be recognized by Swagger or FastAPI as an actual required header. Instead, use a Header parameter to retrieve the actual JWT - I'd think that should work as you expect: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/header-params/ - the reason for this is that the JWT library you're using seems to make the header name configurable: https://github.com/IndominusByte/fastapi-jwt-auth/blob/a6c06193319da0e4976c7472966f3a2891e0d50c/fastapi_jwt_auth/auth_jwt.py#L39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because OpenAPI specs restrict you from declaring `Authorization` header. Other headers that are restricted are `Accept` and `Content-Type`. Use `HTTPBearer` instead.

Source: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#fixed-fields-10